# Zypier Python not running with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, zapier

I'm having trouble with the zapier python integration. I'm working on a API call using urllib2 and cannot use the input_data of zapiers custom variables in my code.

```js
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
zc = input_data['email']
values = """
  {
    "updated": 
      {
        "email": zc,
        "businessUnit": "DE",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "gender": "male"
      }
  }
"""

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-XNG-ApiVersion': '1',
  'X-XNG-AuthToken': 'your Token'
}
request = Request('https://api.crossengage.io/leads/', data=values, headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

I'm receiving error messages:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/tmp/tmpOn6L2p/usercode.py", line 9, in the_function
>       zc = input_data['email']
>   KeyError: 'email'

Can you help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

First off, the solution is a simple one:

```
# KeyError
zc = input_data['email']

# Fixed
zc = input_data['zc']
```

In the input, the left side of the form is the key.

Separately, while you're free to use `urllib2` if you'd like, you also have access to `requests` ([docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)) if you'd like, which may simplify your code.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!